# AndEngine - artifacts while scrolling map (TextureOptions related)

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, andengine

I'm developing 2D Side Scroll Android Game, using AndEngine.

I have problem with tiles quality.

If I will use DEFAULT texture option, for my texture congaing tiles, it doesn't look perfect, contours ARE NOT smooth, etc:

[image]

DEFAULT Texture options, uses such OPEN GL parameters:

```
new TextureOptions(GL10.GL_NEAREST, GL10.GL_NEAREST, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE, GL10.GL_MODULATE, true);
```

But lately I realized, that if I will use such parameters (similar to BILINEAR parameters, except last one)

```
new TextureOptions(GL10.GL_LINEAR, GL10.GL_LINEAR, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE, GL10.GL_MODULATE, true)
```

graphic looks smooth (i would say perfect, check image below)

[image]

Everything would be perfect, but while moving camera (Camera is chasing player) there are visible contours of those sprites, like for example on this screen:

[image]

I have been trying to use different OPEN GL parameters, but with no luck. I would be grateful for some help. With DEFAULT texture option, such problem doesn't exist, but quality is bad. Thanks.

Ps: I have been trying to cast integer on my setCenter method inside camera, but with no luck, some people were saying it should help, but it didn't.

Answer (score 2):

This occurs because the function that is used for smoothing out the textures uses pixels that are outside of the pictures on the Texture Atlas. These are black by default so the pixels on the edges are poisoned by the black area outside.

I have temporarily fixed the issue by extending the picture an all sides by 1px and putting there a copy of the adjacent 1px line from the picture. Then I set my TextureRegion to contain only the middle of the picture with the padding being outside. The results are probably not perfect but the lines are no longer noticeable.

I have seen someone on the AndEngine forums say that in the newest version the problem is fixed, so you may try updating.

Comment: Unfortunately I rather can not update game, I really wanted to stay with GLES1, because it supports older android phones as well.

Comment: I understand that, I'm working with GLES1 version as well. However, older Android devices are disappearing rapidly, depending on your estimate of when the app will be finished, you might want to consider switching to GLES2 now, because when you are finished, older phones may be so rare that you would be better off enjoying the features and performance of GLES2 AndEngine.

Comment: Seems like you are right, I will consider what you said, and will try out gles2 with my game and will check how does it work, thanks.

Comment: I have tried to use BlackPawnTextureAtlasBuilder, and try with different parameters, but in fact there is no change (doesn't matter what values I use.. ) - GLES2. I have no idea now.

Comment: Did you set spacing to at least 1px? In my version of AndEngine, I call the constructor like this: 
new BlackPawnTextureBuilder<IBitmapTextureAtlasSource, BitmapTextureAtlas>(1).
I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes I did, used the same constructors.

Comment: Well, I'm out of ideas now. Try my horrible kludge ( http://pastebin.com/5p8Qg9LW ) and if the problem goes away, you will at least know that it is possible to overcome the problem by preprocessing the textures and tweaking the BlackPawnTextureAtlasBuilder (or just placing the preprocessed textures onto TextureAtlas by hand). If you happen to find the solution in the end, please don't forget to share it with us here. [Disclaimer: Using the kludge in production code would be shameful and it would increase the texture loading time]